# how to connect to sql database with js

Tags: javascript, sql

I have form that to registering some site. I want to check when user is writing username code will check that have or not in database

Comment: By js do you mean code that will run on client side? Like front-end code?  or do you mean NodeJS?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35915

Review this if you want to connect your JS file to your SQL database.

I recommend building out a backend that accepts the username and the backend checks the database and returns a response (using some sort of RESTful API)

Comment: yeah in front-end code. I wrote code in yii2. so I dont know how I do that in php. I want that when input value changes it will be request to db and its result need to seen

Comment: You can see that in registering some site when choosing username, if username is already choosen it alerts u right that moment

Comment: Yes that can be achieved through a call to the backend not directly accessing database from JS

Comment: Learn nodejs  or PHP or python or some language to make a backend server access the database. As this is the best practice in terms of coding and security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use AJAX for this.  The SQL database you speak of is *on the host,* not on the computer that is running the JavaScript.

When the user completes the registration page, you'll use AJAX to send the request to the host.  The host might reply with an `error` response:  "user already exists." *It(!)* is querying the database, which *it(!)* has access to, to determine this.

And ... if I may say ... "the Internet is positively *stuffed* with examples already!"  Check out https://w3schools.com for some of the very-best free tutorials out there. *Good luck!*

Comment: While the rest of your answer is true, I believe the general community recommendation is  not w3schools.com for best practices and examples.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Can you link me to an article or a post with a list of recommended websites to link in future posts? Thanks :)